# How to set shift + tab as keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to set a Keyboard Shortcut in Visual Studio 2013 to Shift + Tab. However, when I put my cursor in the 'Press shortcut keys' textbox and attempt to press the Shift + Tab combination it doesn't put anything into the textbox and tabs back to the previous control!

Is there something that I am missing to let Visual Studio know that I am in fact entering a keyboard shortcut, and not using the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that tab and shift-tab are bound to Windows, therefore even unassigning the Edit.SelectNextControl and Edit.SelectPreviousControl won't do much...

You can hack the XML though -- VS2013 saves changed keyboard shortcuts to CurrentSettings.vssettings
under Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings

1. Make a copy of your CurrentSettings.vssettings file in case. VS overwrites this file everytime it closes as well as when you accept.
2. In VS, go to the keyboard shortcuts setting (Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard)
3. Assign the shortcut you want as Shift+Tab as Ctrl+Shift+Tab instead.
4. Accept + Close VS.
5. Open CurrentSettings.vssettings
6. Do a search for the shortcut string (e.g. Edit.SelectNextControl etc.), alternatively search for Ctrl+Shift+Tab.
7. You should have a long XML line with a part looking like Ctrl+Shift+Tab
8. Remove the Ctrl+ so you're left with Shift+Tab
9. Save, restart VS.

Good luck fighting Windows :)

Comment: I also found that this was useful as a 'reverse lookup' when I was trying to work out what I had assigned to Ctrl+E so that that I could assign a Resharper short cut to Ctrl+E,H

Answer (score 9):

I know the question is a little old, but I found, I think, a better answer. It *is* in fact possible to bind the **TAB** key using the Visual Studio GUI interface. The trick is to select *Text Editor* in the drop-down box for ***Use new shortcut in***, like this:

[image]

1. Open menu Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard dialog.
2. Select your desired command from the command box.
3. In the ***Use new shortcut in*** drop-down box, select *Text Editor*. The default is *Global*, which will NOT allow you to use the **TAB** key.
4. Move your cursor to the ***Press Shortcut Keys*** box.
5. Now you can press the **TAB** key, or any combination, like **Shift-TAB**, **Ctrl-TAB**, etc., and it will go into the shortcut key box.
6. Don't forget to press the **Assign** button! (else nothing happens)

The screen shot shows setting the **TAB** key to Edit.FormatSelection, so that pressing **TAB** correctly indents the current cursor line or block of lines (like Emacs! yay!) rather than inserting tab or space characters.

If you still want access to inserting a tab character, you can add it to another key combination, like **Ctrl-TAB**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, though I am not positive, that Tab and Shift-Tab cannot be bound in VS.  They're tied intimately to indent and unindent.  Tab (and maybe Shift-Tab) is tied to code that triggers completion actions as well.

You might try removing the bindings of Tab and Shift-Tab and then try to bind them to the desired functionality.  Make sure you remember what the bindings were if you remove anything.